# MySQL not inserting data

Tags: mysql

Have created table and already inserted data previously

Can't seem to execute insert commands, haven't tried other at this stage

Have reset mysql, still does it...

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> USE X32334732
Database changed
mysql> INSERT INTO Product (Name, Picture, Type, Description, Sales_Price) VALUE
S ("FIFA 15", "pics/games/fifa.jpg", "Game - ps4", "Soccer Sports Game", 44.95);
```

Thanks for any help.

Thanks 2 Codebird, I was using " not ' .... rookie mistake I'm guessing. TY

Comment: My Table structure...

CREATE TABLE Product (
Pd_Key int AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(35) NOT NULL,
Picture varchar(255),
Type varchar(12),
Description varchar(200) NOT NULL,
Sales_Price decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pdkey_pk PRIMARY KEY (pd_Key));

Comment: Are you getting any error messages returned?

Comment: don't use `"` around strings use `'` and it will insert. You should have noticed it as soon as you typed enter and it didn't run your query

Comment: Seems to work now, thanks man! @codeBird 

May i ask why that is?

Comment: just because mysql works like this. It wants `'` around string and not `"`

Comment: @MasterSketchiggle I was kidding, normally your query should work but it seems like some encoding issue or something.

Answer (score 0):

When the console says ">, that means you are inside a string enclosed with double quotes (") that is not closed.

The string you have posted here doesn't seem to have any unclosed double quotes, but never the less you appear to have one.  Double check your input.

You can get out of your current situation by entering "; to close the quotes and semicolon to execute the command, you'll probably get a syntax error.